# Accidentally changed my only Administrator account to Guest

Tags: user-accounts, windows-10-pro

As the title suggests, I accidentally changed my only admin account to guest today. The account is also my Microsoft account, and I don't have any other accounts on my computer. So I ended up with only a guest account and can't use my laptop to its full potential. Since I'm not the admin anymore, I can't simply do a recovery or create a new admin account. I'm really desperate. What should I do in such case?

I don't want any "hacking" solutions, since the laptop is mine and I'd like to solve this problem in a proper way.

Thanks

*EDIT: Eventually, I solved the problem by reinstalling the system.*

Comment: Follow this tutorial to enable the built-in Administrator account  (https://www.technipages.com/windows-administrator-account-login-screen).  Then in the built-in admin account, make your Microsoft Account member of Admin group.

Comment: @John: These methods all require admin privileges...

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

- [Create Bootable USB Flash Drive](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2376-create-bootable-usb-flash-drive-install-windows-10-a.html)
- [Open a Command Prompt at Boot](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2880-open-command-prompt-boot-windows-10-a.html)
- [Enable Built-in Elevated Administrator Account](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2969-enable-disable-elevated-administrator-account-windows-10-a.html)
- Boot and login as the Built-in Administrator
- Run *Control Panel > User Accounts* and make your account into
  administrator again.
- Disable the Built-in Administrator account, for security.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried this before, but unfortunately, I couldn't search the drive where Windows was installed. Eventually, I solved my problem simply by reinstalling the system, which was not a big deal for me.